# Python: it can't delete a file if I previously opened it (and closed) in Windows File Explorer

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm generating PDF using Weasyprint (Python 3.8). The pdf is stored in a specific folder. Every time after it's generated I click on it to see the preview in File explorer, or even open to review in Adobe Acrobat. After that, if I close it and move the pointer to another file (i.e. deselect it) my code can't remove it. If I don't touch the file in file explorer, my code can remove it without any problem.

I also tried `os.remove` function but the result is the same.

The code I'm using to remove the file:

```
    try:
        if os.path.exists(pdf):
            os.unlink(pdf)
    except Exception as ex:
        log(ex)
```

The code doesn't throw an exception, it just does nothing and after that, the file can't be even open in the file explorer. It says "The file can't be previewed" and if I try to open in Acrobat it shows the error "Access denied".

UPD It turned out Windows Explorer locks pdf files if opened manually or even clicked them. Not sure how to stop it from locking.

Comment: Are you sure it doesn't raise an exception? It's more likely it gets swallowed by the  catch-all `except Exception` and you don't realize it. Do you need to refresh the file explorer to notice the deletion?

Comment: @PranavHosangadi when I tried os.remove it thrown the "Access denied 13" exception. This guy doesn't throw anything but I'm not 100% sure. When I debug it never hits the exception part.